# Functionality breaks when using toggle with 'slow' option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The problem is that when i use the toggle function without any options i.e default options the 'is(':visible')' on the item returns me the correct state.

However when i use toggle("slow"), it reveals incorrect state and always shows the item operated upon by the toggle as visible false. Of course i am checking that inside the callback function so as to be sure that the animation is complete.

please look at the below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var h3 = jQuery("#myAccordion").find('h3');
    jQuery("#myAccordion").find('h3').find('span').addClass("ui-state-active ui-icon");
    jQuery.each(h3, function () {
        jQuery(this).bind('click', function () {
            jQuery(this).next('div').toggle("slow", "swing", callback);
        });
    });
});

function callback () {
    if (jQuery(this).next('div').is(':visible')) {
        alert('visible--' + jQuery(this).next('div').is(':visible'));
        jQuery(this).find('span').removeClass("ui-state-default ui-icon").addClass("ui-state-active ui-icon");
    }
    else {
        alert('visible--' + jQuery(this).next('div').is(':visible')); // always goes into this 'else' even though the item is visible.
        jQuery(this).find('span').removeClass("ui-state-active ui-icon").addClass("ui-state-default ui-icon");
    }
}
```

However the same works perfectly fine when not using the "slow" option with toggle.

Update 2:
Check this out here http://jsfiddle.net/tariquasar/7xt7D/2/

Any pointers...

Update 1: This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tariquasar/7xt7D/

Comment: Try adding `setTimeOut` for 500 ms before executing the callback. And please put your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: @T0X1C , This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tariquasar/7xt7D/

Comment: @devnull69 , here it is http://jsfiddle.net/tariquasar/7xt7D/

Comment: @T0X1C , setTimeOut didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context `this` is not extended to the `callback` function too. You could try doing this. I have updated the [jsfiddle (click here)](http://jsfiddle.net/7xt7D/1/). Ill paste the same here.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var h3 = jQuery("#myAccordion").find('h3');
    jQuery("#myAccordion").find('h3').find('span').addClass("ui-state-active ui-icon"); // first the item is visible
    jQuery.each(h3, function () {
        jQuery(this).bind('click', function () {
console.log(this);
            jQuery(this).next('div').toggle("slow","swing",callback(this));
        });
    });
});

function callback (that) {
    setTimeout( function () {
        console.log(jQuery(that).next('div').is(':visible'));
    if (jQuery(that).next('div').is(':visible')) {
        alert('visible--' + jQuery(that).next('div').is(':visible'));
        jQuery(that).find('span').removeClass("ui-state-default ui-icon").addClass("ui-state-active ui-icon");
    }
    else {
        alert('visible--' + jQuery(that).next('div').is(':visible'));
        jQuery(that).find('span').removeClass("ui-state-active ui-icon").addClass("ui-state-default ui-icon");
    }
    }, 1000);
}
```

I have added a `SetTimeout` to get the result you wanted. The callback function is called after the animation completes. Yes. But not after the CSS changes to `display:none`. CSS change happens a few millisecs later.

> However the same works perfectly fine when not using the "slow" option with toggle.

I'm not really sure about how you got it working with options other than **slow**

Comment: @tariq: Please mark as accepted Answer if it has helped your situation and can help others.

Comment: Thanks pro for your effort. This does work and i accepted it but actually the work that i need to do , now lags a bit.. i mean the class change i do, though it is successful now but there is a time lag and its not instantaneous.

Comment: Regarding "I'm not really sure about how you got it working with options other than slow" check my update.

Comment: @tariq : You could adjust the `setTimeout` accordingly. I just gave a rough value of 1 second. But I doubt it will speed up much may be another 500 ms. You could get rid of the animation if u dont want any lag. Or Better do a CSS3 transition setting transform to easeinout instead of using jquery. This way you will not need timeout. Better performance too.

Comment: yes i did but it works only when its about 610 microseconds..and that lag is noticeable and did you check the other fiddle where it works fine with just toggle. The question still remains that why is it behaving like that ?? how is it able to get the visibility state right with just toggle but not with toggle slow !